# New column created with column headers

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How to get this effect?

Input data:

```
    val1    val2    val3    val4
0   A1.1    A2.1    A3.1    A4.1
1   A1.2    A2.2    A3.2    A4.2
2   A1.3    A2.3    A3.3    A4.3
```

And output data:

```
    new_column  A1.1    A1.2    A1.3       
0   val2        A2.1    A2.2    A2.3
1   val3        A3.1    A3.2    A3.3
2   val4        A4.1    A4.2    A4.3
```

Where A1.1, A1.2, A1.3 are the columns name. 
I tried pivot, unpivot, unstack, but I can't get the intended effect.

Comment: where is your code? Also we don't know unless you try something first.

Comment: @ Mike Tung I tried, but I think that sometimes you have to present the problem without imposing your solutions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html) + [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) + [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = df.set_index('val1').T.rename_axis('new_col').reset_index().rename_axis(None,1)
print (df)
  new_col  A1.1  A1.2  A1.3
0    val2  A2.1  A2.2  A2.3
1    val3  A3.1  A3.2  A3.3
2    val4  A4.1  A4.2  A4.3
```

Comment: That was it! :)

Answer (score 1):

`set_index` +`rename_axis`

```
df.set_index('val1').T.rename_axis(None,1)
Out[499]: 
      A1.1  A1.2  A1.3
val2  A2.1  A2.2  A2.3
val3  A3.1  A3.2  A3.3
val4  A4.1  A4.2  A4.3

df.set_index('val1').T.rename_axis(None,1).reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'new_col'})
Out[524]: 
  new_col  A1.1  A1.2  A1.3
0    val2  A2.1  A2.2  A2.3
1    val3  A3.1  A3.2  A3.3
2    val4  A4.1  A4.2  A4.3
```

Comment: Resetting and rename index is also required here.

Comment: This is a good solution, but @jezrael added a new column at the same time:)

Comment: @Wen now in 100% what was about it :)